# Make Swift UITableView's cell highlight when tapped

Tags: swift, uitableview

How do I make every cell have a dark layer over it unless it is selected, and when selected make the layer fade out?

I have already tried using subviews on the cell but it didn't work because they didn't show up.

Every cell has patternImage as a background image.

Answer (score 0):

One good option in general when wanting to customize tableview cells is to subclass them.

So, for example:

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    var pattern: Pattern?

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

There are a variety of methods you can override.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell